# Product grid won't align properly Woocommerce, Wootique theme

Tags: html, css, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi there I have a problem with the woocommerce product display the grid keeps un-aligning so that there is one on a line and others are right next to each other I have tried adding this bit of custom css:

```css
.woocommerce ul.products li.product,
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
  min-height: 293px !important;
}
```

It solved the problem temporarily until I install the plugin YITH AJAX Product Finder and it seems to have changed back to how it was not sure if that's related...I have tried increasing the height to see if that helped but it hasn't. Any idea's anyone? Here's a link to the product page...

http://casper-creations.com/product-category/caketoppers/

I'm using the wootique theme...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've changed some CSS, to align your product boxes properly. Apply following changes to your CSS -

**style.css - Line 247**

```
ul.products {
   margin-left: 0;
   padding-left: 2px;
   padding-right: 2px;
   padding-top: 2px;
   zoom: 1;
   display: initial; /* Added */
}
```

**style.css - Line 251**

Delete `float: left`and `width: 30.75%`

**custom.css**

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, 
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    display: inline-block; /* Added */
    vertical-align: top; /* Added */
    width: 30%; /* Added */
}
```

**EDIT** - please try to add this at the end of your custom.css, so we can be sure that those rules are not being overwritten by other CSS..

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, 
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
   min-height: 293px !important;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for the speedy reply, I tried your code updates, but now this is only 2 in a row and some are still touching, I believe I did everything you said to do...

Comment: Could you apply it again, so I can take a closer look at it? Maybe some other rule override the added one.

Comment: Ah, sry, my browser cached the old one

Comment: Change the width to 30%.

Comment: Put width: 30%; back into line 251? I have tried it no change